# How do I Use OpenFileDialog to select files or paths

Tags: c#, wpf, file, directory, openfiledialog

I am writing a WPF / C# application, and would like to enable a user to select one (or multiple) files, or one (or multiple) folders, without having to select which option they use initially, but intentionally. In my opinion, the best way to acchieve this goal would be to have a standard FolderBrowserDialog, and as long as the user does not seelct a file, but browses to a path, clicking the open button should select that path.

Practically, this solution does not work, because OpenFileDialog does not allow empty selections, you can hit "open", but nothing will happen. There is one workaround descriped here which allows to enter a fake name like "Selected Folder." as filename. which can afterwards be filtered out, which is a workaround, but not a nice one:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44914/Select-file-or-folder-from-the-same-dialog

This solution has two important weaknesses:
1.) you will have to filter for the fake name
2.) if you paste a filename manually, or select a file first, and then switch the selection to a folder instead, the fake name is not inserted automatically.

of course I am aware there is something like FolderBrowserDialog, which I omit using even if I only wanted to select folders and not files. The reason: this dialog has no possibility to paste paths from clipboard, and I find it annoying to navigate all the way, I rather copy paths from somewhere and paste them, which works perfectly fine in OpenFileDialog, but not in FolderBrowserDialog. Besides, FolderBrowserDialog does not allow to select files and folders.

I have googled a lot, but do not find satisfying solutions, although I am sure many people must obviously face this problem.

**As mentioned, the most elegant way for me would be to make the OpenFileDialog simply allow empty Filename boxes when clicking Open - any way to acchieve this?**

Thanks alot.

Comment: I think there is a conflict of interests in what you want to achieve. If you allow the user to select a folder when they click open, you are having a behavior significantly different than other applications, where you open the folder so you can select something from inside it. Don't you think that could be confusing for users?

Comment: I have actually never liked the standard "folder select dialog" that Windows offers since Windows 95. It is by default not resizable, does not allow pasting of paths in any kind of textbox, and is quite uncomfortable to deal with. As I mentioned, I do not want the users to initially chose if they want to upload a single file, a path, multiple files, or a combination of files and paths. Btw, this last point is one thing I forgot in my original posting: how to select multiple paths? This isn't possible in both kinds of dialogs unfortunately :(

Comment: I am not arguing that the controls are nice, I am just pointing out it might be confusing for users since it goes against what is default in other applications. In any case, I don't think you can do what you want without a weird hack like the article you pointed to. However maybe you can use a third party control, or modify this library to your needs, I think it may provide you at least an start: http://wpfdialogs.codeplex.com/

Comment: Even if somebody would agree that the existing dialogs are sufficient, there still remains the problem that there is no common dialog that allows selection of multiple folders, or even multiple folders AND multiple files at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Letting a user select a directory OR a file using the same dialog is not practical nor intuitively possible. 
However, if you want a solution for selecting a Folder, here it is :

If you don't want to create a custom dialog but still prefer a 100% WPF way and don't want to use separate DDLs, additional dependencies or outdated APIs, I came up with a very simple hack using WPF's Save As dialog for actually selecting a directory.

No using directive needed, you may simply copy-paste the code below !

It should still be very user-friendly and most people will never notice.

The idea comes from the fact that we can change the title of that dialog, hide files, and work around the resulting filename quite easily.

It is a big hack for sure, but maybe it will do the job just fine for your usage...

In this example I have a textbox object to contain the resulting path, but you may remove the related lines and use a return value if you wish...

```
// Create a "Save As" dialog for selecting a directory (HACK)
var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dialog.InitialDirectory = textbox.Text; // Use current value for initial dir
dialog.Title = "Select a Directory"; // instead of default "Save As"
dialog.Filter = "Directory|*.this.directory"; // Prevents displaying files
dialog.FileName = "select"; // Filename will then be "select.this.directory"
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
    string path = dialog.FileName;
    // Remove fake filename from resulting path
    path = path.Replace("\\select.this.directory", "");
    path = path.Replace(".this.directory", "");
    // If user has changed the filename, create the new directory
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    // Our final value is in path
    textbox.Text = path;
}
```

The only issues with this hack are :

- Acknowledge button still says "Save" instead of something like "Select directory", but in a case like mines I "Save" the directory selection so it still works...
- Input field still says "File name" instead of "Directory name", but we can say that a directory is a type of file...
- There is still a "Save as type" dropdown, but its value says "Directory (*.this.directory)", and the user cannot change it for something else, works for me...

Most people won't notice these, although I would definitely prefer using an official WPF way if microsoft would get their heads out of their asses, but until they do, that's my temporary fix.